# Selenium Stucks on pyvirtualdisplay

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyvirtualdisplay

I am running **Selenium python** on server where I need to **hide** **chrome display**. Python script runs most of time but sometimes it **stucks** when it creates **new chromedriver session**. Don't have any idea why it stucks sometimes.

**Snippet Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

chromedriver = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
os.environ['webdriver.chrome.driver'] = chromedriver
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800,600))
display.start()


driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")  => Stuck here 
driver.get("example.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

I just currently set up Selenium on my server. If you get your permission right, try to put this line.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
```

to turn off the sandbox.

Comment: chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/chromedriver to set up permission.